# File picker combobox?

Tags: qt, pyqt

I am currently using the standard recipe for file picking, something like:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QFileDialog, QApplication


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.file = QLineEdit(self)
        self.file.setPlaceholderText('Enter your file')

        self.btn = QPushButton('Select')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.on_btn_clicked)

        layout.addWidget(self.file)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.show()

    def on_btn_clicked(self):
        fp = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            parent=self,
            caption='Select file',
            filter='Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg);;Text files (*.txt);;XML files (*.xml)')
        if fp:
            self.file.setText(fp[0])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I was wondering if there's some (not too complex) way to achieve something like a "File picking ComboBox".

I mean something akin to QFontComboBox where, when I click unto the "open combo" icon, actually a QFileDialog is shown for editing.

Does something like that exist?

I am using PyQt6, but this actually seems a plain QT question.

### UPDATE:

Following @musicamante comment I tried to use `QLineEdit.addAction()` and I also tried subclassing `QLineEdit` to override `focusInEvent`.

The latter somewhat works, even if I'm not fully happy with the result.

OTOH I was unable to make `addAction()` approach work at all.

My current test code follows, comments (or answers) fixing it would be welcome.

```py
import os.path
import sys

from PyQt6.QtGui import QAction, QIcon, QKeySequence
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QFileDialog, QApplication


class FileComboBox(QLineEdit):
    def focusInEvent(self, a0):
        super().focusInEvent(a0)
        self.clearFocus()
        print(self.dialog.selectedFiles(), self.dialog.directory().canonicalPath())
        self.dialog.setDirectory(self.dialog.directory())
        self.dialog.selectFile(os.path.basename(self.text()))
        if self.dialog.exec():
            self.setText(self.dialog.selectedFiles()[0])
            print(self.dialog.selectedFiles(), self.dialog.directory().canonicalPath())

    def __init__(self, caption='Select file', name_filter=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.dialog = QFileDialog(self, caption)
        self.dialog.setNameFilter(name_filter)
        self.dialog.selectFile(self.text())
        self.setPlaceholderText(caption)


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')

        self.action = QAction(QIcon.fromTheme("document-open"), 'Open...')
        self.action.setShortcuts(QKeySequence.StandardKey.Open)
        self.action.setStatusTip("Open an existing file")
        self.action.triggered.connect(self.on_btn_clicked)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.file = QLineEdit(self)
        self.file.setPlaceholderText('Enter your file')
        self.file.addAction(self.action, QLineEdit.ActionPosition.TrailingPosition)

        self.btn = QPushButton('Select')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.on_btn_clicked)

        self.font = FileComboBox(name_filter='Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg);;'
                                             'Text files (*.txt);;'
                                             'XML files (*.xml);;'
                                             'Python files (*.py);;'
                                             'All files (*)')

        layout.addWidget(self.file)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        layout.addWidget(self.font)

        self.show()

    def on_btn_clicked(self):
        fp = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            parent=self,
            caption='Select file',
            filter='Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg);;Text files (*.txt);;XML files (*.xml)')
        if fp:
            self.file.setText(fp[0])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

### UPDATE2:

The above code was fixed as per @musicamante comment and now both approaches work as expected.

Comment: If you mean a QComboBox that shows the contents of a directory in its popup, then you could just set a QFileSystemModel as its model. You obviously need to properly set the `rootIndex()` of the combo in order to "enter" subdirectories (and override its display behavior if you want to show the full path). Alternatively, use QCompleter on a QLineEdit.

Comment: @musicamante: Thanks, I will explore this possibility, but I had in mind something like displaying a full `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(...)` in order to have more control over what's actually displayed (e.g.: `filter`s)

Comment: So, you just want something that "resembles" a combobox, and clicking the arrow button would actually show the dialog? Then use the [`addAction()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlineedit.html#addAction) feature of QLineEdit and connect the action to the function that shows the dialog.

Comment: @musicamante: I tried following your advice, but it seems I'm missing something; can you have a look to updated OP? TiA!

Comment: Look closer at the link above: you need to provide the argument for the side of the line edit on which you want the action appear, otherwise it will just work like a standard `QWidget.addAction(action)`, which just "links" the action to the widget. In your case, it would be `addAction(self.action, QLineEdit.ActionPosition.TrailingPosition)`.